# OpenGL with QT error: ASSERT:"QOpenGLFunctions::isInitialized(d_ptr)". Unable to create OpenGL context

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es

I have recently made my first OpenGL program rendering a cube, which I extended to include some other basic features (rotate, zoom, pan, mouse selection of vertices). However, I think the program was using some version of OpenGL ES x.x because I could not use glReadPixels with gl_depth_component to enable mouse selection of only visible vertices.

To fix this I've modified my old program to manually specify the default surface format in my main function to OpenGL version 3.0, but now the program throws the following error when it tries to create an instance of GLWidget.

ASSERT:"QOpenGLFunctions::isInitialized(d_ptr)"

My main function (main.cpp):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(16);     
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setVersion(3,0);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat( format);
    QApplication a(argc, argv); 
    MainWindow w;                                          //breakpoint here - step into
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Stepping into this breakpoint leads me to my MainWindow constructor(mainwindow.cpp):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);                                       //breakpoint here - step into
    ui->GLwidget2->getmainwindowpointer(this);
    connect(ui->actionTop,SIGNAL(triggered()),ui->GLwidget2,SLOT(settopview()));
    connect(ui->actionRight, SIGNAL(triggered()), ui->GLwidget2, SLOT(setrightview()));
    connect(ui->actionIso,SIGNAL(triggered()),ui->GLwidget2,SLOT(setisoview()));
    //connect(ui->checkBox_perspective,SIGNAL(released()),ui->GLwidget2,SLOT(setperspective()));
    connect(ui->checkBox_legend, SIGNAL(released()), ui->GLwidget2, SLOT(setlegend()));
    connect(ui->checkBox_edges, SIGNAL(released()), ui->GLwidget2, SLOT(setedges()));
    connect(ui->checkBox_faces, SIGNAL(released()), ui->GLwidget2, SLOT(setfaces()));
    connect(ui->actionFind_vertex,SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),ui->GLwidget2,SLOT(startvertexsearch()));
    connect(ui->actionFit_to_screen,SIGNAL(triggered()),ui->GLwidget2,SLOT(fittoscreen()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_selectMode,SIGNAL(released()),ui->GLwidget2,SLOT(setSelectMode()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_cancelSelect,SIGNAL(released()),ui->GLwidget2,SLOT(setCancelSelectMode()));
}
```

Stepping into this breakpoint leads me to ui_mainwindow.h, which creates the objects in my mainwindow and reaches this line:

[code above...]

```
    pushButton = new QPushButton(centralWidget);
    pushButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));

    verticalLayout_2->addWidget(pushButton);


    horizontalLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout_2);

    GLwidget2 = new GLWidget(centralWidget);                 /break point here - step into
```

[code below...]

This all runs fine until the constructor of my GLWidget is called...
(glwidget.cpp)

```
#include "glwidget.h"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) :
QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{                                        //breakpoint here
    alpha = 0;
    beta = 0;
    distance = defaultdistance;
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(16);
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setVersion(3,0);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    this->setFormat(format);
}
```

As soon as I continue past this breakpoint the ASSERT error is thrown. Debugging it leads me to this place in qopenglfunctions.h

[code above...]

```
inline GLuint QOpenGLFunctions::glCreateProgram()
{
#ifdef QT_OPENGL_ES_2
    GLuint result = ::glCreateProgram();
#else
    Q_ASSERT(QOpenGLFunctions::isInitialized(d_ptr));       //this line
    GLuint result = d_ptr->CreateProgram();
#endif
    Q_OPENGL_FUNCTIONS_DEBUG
    return result;
}
```

[codde below...]

The value of d_ptr at this time is NULL, which I guess is the cause of the error. Do I need to perform some initialisation of desktop OpenGL versions that aren't required for OpenGL ES versions?

I'm still new to OpenGL so any help would be appreciated!

**Update** I'm not sure what was happening, but after merging my updated code with my older working code everything worked fine. Hopefully this happens to no-one else!

Comment: Note that OpenGL 3.0 doesn't have profiles, and it's a very weird version to ask for. Do you have an OpenGL 3.0 capable GPU and suitable drivers?

Comment: Ok Peppe, what version of OpenGL do you suggest I try to use? My GPU has 100% compatibility with OpenGL 4.3 and earlier with the latest drivers, so that shouldn't be a problem. From my perspective I don't particularly mind which version of OpenGL I end up using as long as I can use depth testing via glReadPixels.

Comment: Does anything change if you ask for 3.2 core?

Answer (score 8):

You need to add   `initializeOpenGLFunctions();`  into your `GLWidget::initGL()` function.